# Wrong parameter count when calling strstr function

Tags: php

I am getting

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Wrong parameter count for strstr()
```

for the following code

```
$ext = strrev(strstr(strrev($file), ".", TRUE));
```

What should I do?

**Update**

In stead of `$ext = strrev(strstr(strrev($file), ".", TRUE));`

I have used this.

```
$ext = strrev(substr(strrev($file)), 0 ,strpos(strrev($file), ":"));
```

Still getting the same error for `substr` and `strrev`

This is kind of wierd. Is it related with version problem?

Comment: `substr(strrev($file))` is not enough parameters to `substr`.

Comment: how should i write that?

Comment: Are you just trying to get the extension of a filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as others have pointed out, the third parameter of strstr appeared only in PHP 5.3.0. Maybe what you wanted to do is simply

```
$ext = substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1);
```

or better

```
$dotpos = strrpos($file, '.');
if ($dotpos === false) {
   $ext = ''; // or other special handling like, e.g., $ext = false;
} else {
   $ext = substr($file, $dotpos + 1);
}
```

This will let you handle separately the cases of a missing and of a trailing dot (`pathinfo()` returns an empty string in both cases), and also avoids all intermediate strings (just not to waste CPU time)

Answer (score 1):

As per [the docs](https://www.php.net/strstr), you need to update your PHP version to `>= 5.3.0` to get the `[, bool $before_needle = false ]` parameter. It was added in `5.3.0`.

If you're just trying to get the extension of a file, you should use `pathinfo`, like so:

```
$ext = pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

```
$user = strstr($email, '@', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0
```

Check your php version. the 'before_needle' parameter was only added in php version 5.3.0

Maybe you need to upgrade or you will have to remove the parameter.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Try this simple function:**

```
<?php

function my_strstr($haystack, $needle, $before_needle = false)
{
    $output        = false;
    $before_needle = $before_needle === true ? true : false;
    if (is_string($haystack) && is_string($needle) && is_bool($before_needle)) {
        switch ($before_needle) {
            case true:
                $output = substr($haystack, 0, strpos($haystack, $needle));
                break;
            case false:
                $output = strstr($haystack, $needle);
                break;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```